# EC2/Windows: Install apps, save image (AMI), use later?

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I need to test with various versions of applications running on windows. I'm tempted to use something like EC2, with the idea being:

- Fire up a base EC2 windows instance. Install the app (eg. QuickBooks)
- Save the resulting image as an AMI
- Test away
- Turn off the instance

At a later date:

- Restore the AMI onto a new instance
- Test again with the clean instance

Questions:

- Is this feasible/advisable?
- We have licenses for the software we want to test with, but are there technical licensing issues with having the software (eg. QuickBooks) run once the image is restore?
- Any particular tools / scripts we should be aware of for helping with this? We're experienced on the linux side with EC2, but not on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this feasible/advisable?

Yes it is, totally, and it is pretty straightforward to implement.  That's one of the big attraction with EC2 (and Infrastructure as a Service offerings) - you get to pay by the hour/resource instead of paying for hardware/networking up front.

> We have licenses for the software we
>   want to test with, but are there
>   technical licensing issues with having
>   the software (eg. QuickBooks) run once
>   the image is restore?

Unless your license is for one machine and you don't run two instances of your AMI at once, you should be ok.

> Any particular tools / scripts we
>   should be aware of for helping with
>   this? We're experienced on the linux
>   side with EC2, but not on windows.

Not particularly.  There's nothing odd about running Windows on EC2 when compared to running Linux outside of pricing, creating AMIs of instance-store backed instances (you have to use ec2-bundle-instance calls instead of ec2-create-image calls), and the usual differences between the OSs.

Answer (score 1):

This should be totally fine; as long as you don't try to run more than one instance at a time of your custom AMI with the installation of QuickBooks or whatever, you shouldn't run into any licensing issues.